# Running a program on command prompt that creates a windows service, but remains executing on command prompt until I issue a ctrl c

Tags: windows, service, command-prompt

I created a program that creates a windows service to run as a daemon in the background.

My problem is this, when I run the program on the command prompt, it stays in-line, executing the program until I issue a ctrl c to cancel the execution of the program, even if I have already closed the windows service in the background.

Are there any commands I can run off the command prompt so it knows to go to the next line so that the command prompt can be used while the service is running in the background?

thanks

Comment: What language did you write the program in? Show us the code that executes the service.

Comment: It sounds as if your program isn't exiting, presumably due to a bug in your code.  Fix the bug and the problem will go away!  Have you tried running it in a debugger to see what it is doing?